# Как найти одинаковые строки в таблице без первичного ключа и без уникальных значений в столбцах?

Tags: sql, стандарт, повторы, дублирование

Как найти и отобразить одинаковые строки (по всем полям) в таблице, не имеющую первичный ключ и уникальные значения полей? Желателен код по стандарту  ANSI SQL, не зависящий от СУБД.

Comment: Вам нужно что? Посчитать их или отобразить? Отобразить в каком виде? "Одинаковые" по конкретному полю?

Comment: Отобразить их, одинаковые по всем полям.

Comment: и много в таблице полей?

Comment: ну столбцов примерно штук 20

Comment: Ну одним запросом будет сложно)))

Comment: Ну не обязательно прям одним запросом, главное что бы надёжно и правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример для таблицы с двумя столбцами

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Field1, Field2
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

upd:обязательное перечисление всех полей

Comment: При частичном совпадении, когда часть полей совпадает, а часть нет, результат может быть неверным

Comment: Если все поля перечислить, то будет норм.

Answer (score 0):

Вывести все строки таблицы MY_TABLE, у которых есть одинаковые значения поля REPEAT_FIELD:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT REPEAT_FIELD, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY REPEAT_FIELD
) AS T2 ON T1.REPEAT_FIELD = T2.REPEAT_FIELD
WHERE T2.CNT > 1
```

синтаксис от mySQL, но вроде стандартно все

Comment: мне кажется лучше в подзапросе сделать having count(*)>1, что бы отсечь не нужные записи до join

Comment: можно и так, добавьте свой вариант как ответ с пояснением